# What do you suggest as a robust person tracking ROS-based solution using the Kinect

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am looking for a robust person tracking ROS-based solution for the Kinect. I know there exist a number of different packages but I was wondering which one you recommend as a robust tracking solution when using specifically the Kinect.

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249182/what-do-you-suggest-as-a-robust-person-tracking-ros-based-solution-using-the-kinect/) by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2016-12-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tommi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23616/tommi/) on 2016-12-01**:
Can you provide some more details? Using Kinect I assume you are targeting indoor application? Can you assume the ground is planar? Are you having a static camera or Kinect mounted on a robot?

**Comment by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on 2016-12-01**:
Thank for your prompt reply. I am targeting an indoor application. The Kinect is mounted on the robot at the height of approximately 1.2 m and the ground can be assumed to be planar. the robot can move up to 2 .5 m/s.

**Comment by [Tommi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23616/tommi/) on 2016-12-01**:
Then I don't know a good ready-made solution. You should maybe clarify as well if you are thinking of detector and tracker as a package deal or tracker only.

**Comment by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on 2016-12-01**:
I need a detector and tracker in combination. I could limit the speed of the robot to an extent. I am more considered about the robustness of the detection-tracking of the people (even at the expense of having to use lower speeds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found that openpose and its wrappers seem very promising at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) with karma: 88 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0